# Evaluate limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^{4}}e^{\sqrt t }\cdot\sin t \ dt}{x^{8}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

$f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto  \mathbb{R}$; $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x^{4}}e^{\sqrt t }\cdot\sin t \ dt$

I need to find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^{8}}$

The right answer is $1/2$

I tried to solve the integral by parts but I get stucked.Also I tried to rewrite the integral then to use the fact that $F'=f$ and to use L'hopital but the calculation are too long.Some ideas?

Answer (score 6):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_0^{x^4}e^{\sqrt{t}}\sin t\ dt}{x^8} = \lim_{u\to 0^+} \frac{\int_0^u e^{\sqrt{t}} \sin t \ dt}{u^2} = \lim_{u\to 0^+} \frac{e^{\sqrt{u}}\sin u}{2u} = \frac{1}{2} $$